# Tez vertex error shown while execution of query in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, tez

can any one explain what is VERTEX_FAILURE error   in Hive while using Tez execution engine ? Also what is the root cause of it?

Answer (score 3):

This error is because Tez containers are not allocating enough memory to run the query.

Solution: you have to increase memory for resources with adjusting following parameters.

```
tez.am.resource.memory.mb=4096 
tez.am.java.opts=-server -Xmx3276m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC 
hive.tez.container.size=4096 
hive.tez.java.opts=-server -Xmx3276m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used mr instead of tez, and it's working

Comment: but tez is much faster then mr and now mr is deprecated in hive2 so if you are planning for working with large amount of data then you have to used tez.